# Insert CRLF into a CSV file

Tags: c#, csv

I am iterating a datatable of C# and converting it into a CSV. I could use Environment.Newline to represent an end of one row and beginning of newline, ie CRLF (in CSV parlance).

But, is there any other way of representing a CRLF in a string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Environment.NewLine` is platform independent.

Nevertheless... on Windows it is `\r\n`. So your string could be:

```
var content = "This is one Line 1\r\nand this is on Line 2";
```

Comment: I understand the advantages of Ennvironment.Newline. But, I am actually picking up the CRLF character from a variable and then appending it to the String which holds the row. So, E.Newline will appear as is. That is why I needed an alternative. I doubt if my app will ever be deployed on another platform.